# Add together n-dimensions in a three dimensional array in R

Tags: arrays, r, function, sum, addition

everyone! I have a very straight problem. I have a three dimensional array called **w**, like this:

```
> w
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.5  0.5  0.5
[2,]  0.5  0.5  0.5

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.1  0.1  1.0
[2,]  0.5  0.5  0.5
```

Now, it is just a **representation**, so this is not the actual data.

The thing is that I have add together the elements from the third dimensions, like `w[1, 1, 1] + w[1, 1, 2] + w[1, 1, 3]`, but I don't know how many members the third dimension will have. I cannot do it in a for loop because it is within a nested for loop already (two for loops).

So, I basically have to add together `w[, , 1] + w[, , 2] + w[, , 3]....`

I tried something like

```
for (k in 1:dims(w)[3]) # it is one of the for loops
lapply(w[, , k], '+')
```

but it only prints the `w[, , 1]` and that is it.

*In c++, I think you would simply write y += w[, , n].*

I would really appreciate some thoughts on how I should approach this or maybe a solution :).

*edit: a very embarrassing typo.

Comment: Try with `rowSums`, and `colSums` . So using data below. `rowSums(my.array, dims=2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this does what you want:

```
# sample data
w<-array(sample(1:4),dim=c(3,3,3))

# sum over dimensions 1 and 2
apply(w, MARGIN=c(1, 2), sum)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It does it perfectly. 

It also proves, that there is a lot of reading that I still have to do :)